# Как разбить докториновский Array collection по 10 элементов?

Tags: php, symfony, коллекции, doctrine2

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста как можно на уровне докториновской array colletion сделать данную разбивку?

есть коллекция из 500 объектов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

не могу понять как сделать чтобы у меня было 50 Array collection по 10 объектов в каждой? как в array_chunk указал колличество и функция разбила плоский массив по указанному колличеству..

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [slice](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-collections/en/latest/index.html#slice) метод:

```
<?php

$collection = new ArrayCollection([1, 2, 3]);
$collections = [];

$perPage = 10;
$pages = count($collection) / $perPage;

for ($index = 0; $index <= $pages; $index++) {
   $collections[] = $collection->slice($index * $perPage, min($perPage, count($collection) - index * $perPage));
}
```

Процесс

Для каждой страницы, извлечь срез (массив) из оригинального массива, с началом номера страницы * кол-во на странице, с длиной кол-ва на странице, либо остатка до конца массива если осталось меньше.